# ZF2: Command to create config for DB fails because no DB config

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2 and trying to create console command for filling db config

```
php public/index.php env install stable --dbu=root --dbp=root --dbn=panel100
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in /home/seyfer/www/site.loc/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/seyfer/www/site.loc/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'username', 'password', Array)
    #1 /home/seyfer/www/site.loc/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php(45): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'username', 'password', Array)
    #2 /home/seyfer/www/site.loc/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'username', 'password', Array)
    #3 /home/seyfer/www/site.loc/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(429): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
    #4 /home/seyfer/www/site.loc/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(3 in /home/seyfer/www/site.loc/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 946
```

So no I have chicken and egg problem. Command fails because there is no DB  config, but command should create this config.

How to not initialize services when call this command?

My controller code is

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use ZendMover\Copier;

class EnvController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function installAction()
    {
        $env = $this->getRequest()->getParam('env');
        $dbu = $this->getRequest()->getParam('dbu');
        $dbp = $this->getRequest()->getParam('dbp');
        $dbn = $this->getRequest()->getParam('dbn');

        try {
            $environment = new Environment($env, new Copier());
            $result      = $environment->installEnv($env, $dbu, $dbp, $dbn);

            return $result ? "Success\n" : '';
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was solved it with Symfony Console component.

But how to solve it using Zend Console?